# How can I make my ball in roblox studio reset it's position after waiting 7 seconds?

Tags: lua, roblox

How can I make my ball in roblox studio reset it's position after waiting 7 seconds?
After multiple tutorials I made this which simply didn't work.

```
local ball = script.parent

while true do
    wait(7)
    ballPart.Position = Vector3.new(102, 64.9, 232.8)
end
```

Anyone know how I can do this? Thank You.

(i think i worte this part in the description)

Answer (score 0):

`ballPart` is not defined
try

```lua
local ball = script.parent

while true do
    wait(7)
    ball.Position = Vector3.new(102, 64.9, 232.8)
end
```

instead

Comment: Still doesn't work .I'm not sure what  I'm missing. Is there a possibility it can teleport after touching another part?